# How to remove commas and single quotes from list

Tags: python, list

how would i remove the single quotes and commas from this list?

```
coord=[ ['0',' bR ',' bKn ',' bB ',' bQ ',' bK ',' bB ',' bKn ',' bR '],
        ['1',' bP ',' bP  ',' bP ',' bP ',' bP ',' bP ',' bP  ',' bP '],
        ['2',' _  ','  _  ',' _  ',' _  ',' _  ','  _ ','  _  ','  _ '],
        ['3',' _  ','  _  ',' _  ',' _  ',' _  ','  _ ','  _  ','  _ '],
        ['4',' _  ','  _  ',' _  ',' _  ',' wK ','  _ ','  _  ','  _ '],
        ['5',' _  ','  _  ',' _  ',' _  ',' _  ','  _ ','  _  ','  _ '],
        ['6',' wP ','  _  ',' _  ',' _  ',' _  ','  _ ','  _  ','  _ '],
        ['7',' wR ',' wKn ',' wB ',' wQ ',' _  ',' wB ',' wKn ',' wR '],
        [' ',' 1  ','  2  ','  3 ',' 4  ',' 5  ',' 6  ',' 7  ' ,'  8 '] ]
```

Comment: You have a list of lists of strings there. What data type are you hoping to end up with? Just a single string that is the concatenation of all those strings?

Comment: There are no commas or single quotes in the list. I only see those necessary to generate the list syntax in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify what it means to you to "remove" them.  The single quotes are Python's syntax for character strings.  The commas are Python syntax for list elements.  Without those bits of "syntactic sugar", you do not have a Python list.

Comment: Are you trying to get a string representation of this list?  Something like `'\n'.join([''.join(x) for x in coord])`

Comment: i was not clear enough, sorry. What i want is for there to be no single quotes or commas when the list is printed out.

Comment: What is the *reason* the print representation is important? I just want to make absolutely sure this is not an XY problem.

Comment: i would like to make it look much cleaner than it is right now when printed

Comment: for sublist in coord: print (" ".join(sublist))

Comment: thank you very much! @KennyOstrom

Comment: You should use width specifiers in the print, rather than manually editing each data entry to have a specific width. Let the output functions handle outputing tasks. Should I elaborate in an answer?

Comment: your question really should be: how do I union or join this list of lists?
also, by the looks of it that seems to be a grid ... something that you find extensively with pandas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Based on the comments it sounds like you are looking for:

```
for x in coord:
    print (" ".join(x)+"\n")
```